# K-theory tags (versus algebraic-k-theory and topological-k-theory)

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

A [user raised the question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/2037#2037) (I'm trans-posting here so it gets higher visibility) whether we really have the need for three separate tags [k-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k-theory), [algebraic-k-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-k-theory), and [topological-k-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-k-theory).

I do not know enough about K theory myself to be comfortable making the call. Please discuss. If we reach a consensus, I (or Qiaochu) will implement and document the change on the tag-merger thread.

Answer (score 3):

One of the issues is that there is not a lot of traffic in these tags (I imagine). In general I think having more tags is best, this may or may not be one of them. One possible reason for the plain K-theory tag is that there is an arxiv tag that is more applicably described by K-theory than the other two. In the early days, I think people able to make tags were trying to mimic the MO policy of having one for each arxiv area.

I think that there are conceivable questions about K-theory that it might be misleading to tag as just algebraic or topological K-theory. But I strongly doubt those questions would be asked here.

I personally use tags to learn about the views of the asker, and what type of people they want to see the question.

Some of the above are just general comments.

Comment: @Sean: can you take a look at the 4 questions currently tagged as k-theory and say whether any of them is more reasonably tagged k-theory instead of algebraic- or topological- ?

Comment: @Willie Well, 3 of this questions are clearly about topological K-theory but 1 is about K-theory of $C^*$-algebras -- and for this one tag (just) "k-theory" looks natural.

Comment: @Grigory: in this case we'll leave the three tags alone. Thanks.

Comment: The reason I asked was the very observation that Grigory M made, namely that it appeared that the [tag:k-theory] was being used instead of [tag:topological-k-theory], but I guess that with such low traffic, it won't cause a big problem.

Comment: @Grigory: But those questions are about *topological* K-theory of C*-algebras as opposed to algeraic.

Comment: @Rasmus: in this case you are welcome to retag those as topological K-theory. Then the unused k-theory tag will disappear itself after a day or so. Thanks!

Comment: @Rasmus: I don't know if I believe that. There is a nice correspondence called Swan's theorem and the Gelfand-Naimark theorem that essentially say they coincide in the situation of $C^*$ algebra. It is $C^*$ algebra K-theory, which corresponds to topological K-theory via the above result and has $K_0$ and $K_1$ the same as algebraic K-theory. Topological K-theory would have to mean bundles over the topological space underlying the $C^*$ algebra which doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Rasmus I'd say, there is topological K-theory (i.e. K-theory of spaces), algebraic K-theory (i.e. K-theory of rings/schemes) and some other variants -- including K-theory of C*-algebras. But I'm not an expert.

Comment: The real point is, I'm interested in questions about topological K-theory -- but I won't be able to answer any question about K-theory of C*-algebras. So it would be convenient (for me, at least) to separate them.

Comment: @Sean: Are you sure that, for C*-algebras, algebraic K-theory coincides with (topological/normal/C*-algebra) K-theory? [This article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6W9F-4CRY390-R9&_user=10&_coverDate=01%2F31%2F1988&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1729537595&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=88f4b679024c9a58fe9a300899e1de3f&searchtype=a) seems to indicate that this is not true in general.

Comment: The terminology *topological* K-theory seems to be used for C*-algebras when "normal" K-theory needs to be distinguished from algebraic K-theory.

Comment: Given the ongoing discussion, it seems I've marked acceptance too early. So I've undone the acceptance.

Comment: @Rasmus: I guess this is an issue of terminology. We have a $C^*$ algebra person here as well as someone who does operator algebra stuff, and they don't call it algebraic or topological K-theory. But this is just terminology, so I guess it doesn't matter. $K_0$ and $K_1$ of a $C^*$ algebra are almost exactly the algebraic K-theory of the ring. Maybe the above article is hinting that our projections should be continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (algebraic-K-theory), (topological-K-theory) and (operator-K-theory)?

But probably, we should just wait.

Comment: I'm iffy on operator-K-theory. Like I said, I'm no expert on it, but during grad school I have seen talks on the former two, but not explicitly something titled the last. So I suspect the term "operator K theory" maybe too specialised for this site.

Comment: Probably you're right.

Comment: I think maybe we should wait until someone asks the question.